# datastax-agent and OpsCenter not communicating on fresh AWS EC2 datastax instance

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I've got a two-node Amazon Web Services cassandra cluster created using "DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.5.1-pv". OpsCenter is running on node 0, as is the datastax-agent, but they don't seem to be completely connected. OpsCenter says 0 of 0 agents connected and the connection icon next to "New Cluster" is blinking red.

OpsCenter screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Tnx.png

Comment: It's just a case-sensitive keyspace, it would be useful to see a snippet of the Hector code for the query (specifically the part where you mention the keyspace).

Comment: That's from the datastax-agent, so I don't have code for that. But knowing that the quotes just mean a case sensitive keyspace is useful.

Comment: Edited significantly because Lyuben's comment made clear that my first idea for what was going wrong was way off base.

Comment: I think you haven't configured opscenter to see the cluster at all, I dont see any cassandra nodes or anything in than SS.  Here's [a screenshot with a single node](http://prikachi.com/images/781/7524781T.png) in opscenter. In the top right corner under **Cluster Actions** you can select **Add nodes**.

Comment: The fact that it displays "0 of 0" indicates that opscenterd can't connect to the IPs/hostnames provided in the cluster configuration.  Verify that the cluster is up, and edit the connection settings in OpsCenter via Settings->Cluster Connections.  You can also check opscenterd.log for any more information about why it can't connect

Answer (score 0):

a nodetool status would really help.

check the agent logs on either of the nodes when the starts, if you don't see any errors, try "adding a new cluster" then "manage existing cluster" and add the seed IPs of your two nodes, opscenter will try to update the agents if needed.

BTW: upgrade to opscenter 5.1, there are a lot of bug already fixed